# IF and AND to check one value in a range

Tags: excel

I think I am seeing too many formulas now and have kind of hit a wall.

Basically I have a worksheet and it contains a value in cell A2. This is my current project phase

I then have a table, called 'Table1' and it has a column for 'Phase', which contains a range of unique values, one of which will match cell A2.

Also in Table1, I have another column called 'Overrun' which shows a Yes or No value to indicate that that phase has overrun (this is calculated by checking some dates).

So far so good.

I am now trying in a new cell (cell I2) to put a Yes or No if the CURRENT phase has the 'Overrun' value set to Yes. i.e. Where the Phase column matches cell A2, and the Overrun value for that phase is = Yes.

My query currently sits at this, but it is giving me a #VALUE result and I am not sure what I am missing:

=IF(AND(Table1[Phase]=A2,Table1[Overrun]="Yes"),"Yes","No").

My guess is that it is checking the full range of Overrun instead of the specific row for the current phase, but I am not sure how to check that with the AND.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of sheet - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVevF.jpg

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at the vlookup function, it should do what you want.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the answer, I just don't know how to plug it into that formula

Comment: It was the right answer in the end as well, see comment on other post for this where the answer is - =VLOOKUP(A2, Table1, 2)

Comment: Apologies..  I am new here.  I don't have the option yet to comment on a question (reputation level too low).

Answer (score 0):

If the formula referencing the table is not in the same row as the table, then it shows #VALUE, like in the image.  Note that I did add a $ to keep the A2 value constant across all of the rows.

[image: excel screenshot]

[Here is a resource](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) about using structured references in excel tables.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am trying to get a distinct value in one cell with the yes or no answer.

Comment: use the cell reference, e.g. C4 or is that what you are trying to find, what cell it is?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I dynamically want the new cell to indicate if my current phase has overrun so the sheet looks like this ![Example](http://imgur.com/a/ETNrd) where I want cell I2 to update automatically if I update cell A2 to a different phase

Comment: @Chris please put the link your original post and not a comment.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2, Table1, 2)` does what you want, I don't think you need an IF or AND but go ahead and try it

Comment: I am an absolute idiot, thank you. That looks like it will do the trick. I think I should go home now!